# Session timeout leads to Access Denied in Spring MVC when CSRF integration with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf-protection

I have Integrated CSRF token with Spring Security in my Spring MVC Project. Everything work properly with CSRF token, token will be send from client side to server side.

I have changed my `logout` process to make it `POST` method to send CSRF token and its works fine.

I have face problem when session timeout is occurred, it needs to be redirected to spring default logout URL but it gives me `Access Denied` on that URL.

How to override this behavior.

I have include below line in Security config file

```
   <http>
         //Other config parameters
        <csrf/>
   </http>
```

Please let me know if anyone needs more information.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question is a bit old, but answers are always useful.

First, this is a known issue with session-backed CSRF tokens, as described in the docs: [CSRF Caveats - Timeouts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-timeouts).

To solve it, use some Javascript to detect imminent timeouts, use a session-independent CSRF token repository or create a custom `AccessDeniedHandler` route. I chose the latter:

Config XML:

```
<http>
    <!-- ... -->
    <access-denied-handler ref="myAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<bean id="myAccessDeniedHandler" class="package.MyAccessDeniedHandler">
    <!-- <constructor-arg ref="myInvalidSessionStrategy" /> -->
</bean>
```

MyAccessDeniedHandler:

```
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    /* ... */
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (exception instanceof MissingCsrfTokenException) {
            /* Handle as a session timeout (redirect, etc).
            Even better if you inject the InvalidSessionStrategy
            used by your SessionManagementFilter, like this:
            invalidSessionStrategy.onInvalidSessionDetected(request, response);
            */
        } else {
            /* Redirect to a error page, send HTTP 403, etc. */
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can define the custom handler as a `DelegatingAccessDeniedHandler`:

```
<bean id="myAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.DelegatingAccessDeniedHandler">
    <constructor-arg name="handlers">
        <map>
            <entry key="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.MissingCsrfTokenException">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.session.InvalidSessionAccessDeniedHandler">
                    <constructor-arg name="invalidSessionStrategy" ref="myInvalidSessionStrategy" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="defaultHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
            <property name="errorPage" value="/my_error_page"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by mdrg is right on, and I also implemented a custom `AccessDeniedHandler` which I submit for your consideration:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.MissingCsrfTokenException;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCache;

/**
 * Intended to fix the CSRF Timeout Caveat 
 * (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-timeouts).
 * When the session expires and a request requiring CSRF is received (POST), the
 * missing token exception is handled by caching the current request and 
 * redirecting the user to the login page after which their original request will
 * complete. The intended result is that no loss of data due to the timeout will
 * occur.
 */
public class MissingCsrfTokenAccessDeniedHandler extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl {
  private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
  private String loginPage = "/login";

  @Override
  public void handle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, AccessDeniedException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (exception instanceof MissingCsrfTokenException && isSessionInvalid(req)) {
      requestCache.saveRequest(req, res);
      res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + loginPage);
    }
    super.handle(req, res, exception);
  }

  private boolean isSessionInvalid(HttpServletRequest req) {
    try {
      HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
      return session == null || !req.isRequestedSessionIdValid();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  public void setRequestCache(RequestCache requestCache) {
    this.requestCache = requestCache;
  }

  public void setLoginPage(String loginPage) {
    this.loginPage = loginPage;
  }
}
```

Wired up via java config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(getAccessDeniedHandler());
    ...
  }

   public AccessDeniedHandler getAccessDeniedHandler() {
    return new MissingCsrfTokenAccessDeniedHandler();
  }
}
```