# Spring Security Csrf token after session timeout

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

There is a form with POST method and `csrf_token = '1'` (for brevity).

After the session timeout, I submit the form and get redirected to login page. After logging in, I can see the old token (in the request) and the new generated token ('2') in `CsrfFilter` (in the debugger). Since these don't match, I get an `InvalidCsrfTokenException` and then a 403 error.

How should Spring normally behave in this case?

I checked these posts:

- [Getting 403 with CSRF token in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517107/getting-403-with-csrf-token-in-spring-security)
- [Session timeout leads to Access Denied in Spring MVC when CSRF integration with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654206/session-timeout-leads-to-access-denied-in-spring-mvc-when-csrf-integration-with)

but they both look like workarounds. Is there no better option? Why wouldn't the Spring team include one of them as a default?

Comment: The point of a CSRF token is to prevent CSRF attacks.  This basically entails storing a token in the user session, which by the premise of your question, has expired, and thus, is gone.  Both the "workarounds" in the questions you linked to are viable options.

Comment: We ran into this same issue and resolved it using a custom `AccessDeniedHandler` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47399348/225217)